# Push Notification as update for iOS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have an app on the AppStore and I wish to add push notification feature as an upadate. Now if the user updates the app, i would like to notify him if wants to have push notifications from the app.

How do I achieve it?

Thanks

Comment: If you have code for push notification in your new app then the app itself will ask for permission

Answer (score 1):

Enable push notifications for your app bundle identifier in developer.apple.com

and create distribution SSL certificates for push notifications [Steps to create APNS certificates](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

Once the app is updated to AppStore,the users with updated version gets a alert message **to enable the Push notification permission** defuatly

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to apple developer documentation, they have a guide to do it step by step. Here is the link.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringPushNotifications/ConfiguringPushNotifications.html

When sending push notifications be aware of sandbox (when connected to XCode) and production mode (Ad-Hoc or app published).

I hope is useful.